# Don't understand why my addEventListener don't work

Tags: javascript, class, methods, static, addeventlistener

Dears,

I am new in programming, below is my program:

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');

class Bee {
  static welcome_tips() {
    return 'Welcome to here';
  }

  static welcome() {
    p.innerHTML = this.welcome_tips();
  }
};

p.addEventListener('click', () => {
  Bee.welcome();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>static method practice</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p></p>
</body>

</html>
```

My idea is when somebody click on the `<p>` in the HTML, a statement "Welcome to here" will be shown.  For some reason, I want the below two static methods to be included in my program.  However, it shows nothing when i click on the HTML.  I found when i just use Bee.welcome(), the statement "Welcome to here" is shown automatically.  Could you tell me where i get wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: The `<p>` is empty, there's nothing to click on.

Comment: If I change it to `<p>Click here</p>`, it works when I click on that.

Comment: then how to correct it?

Comment: Just put something in the HTML to click on. Or use CSS to give it a height, width, and background color so you see something there.

Comment: There is no blank <p> area. If it's empty, it takes up no space. You can't click on nothing. Maybe you want to put the event listener on the window, not `p`?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I tried your solution and it really work.  But is there a method even <p> is blank, when i click the blank <p> area, the statement can be shown?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, exactly what you just mentioned, anywhere on the page..

Comment: Then use `window.addEventListener` instead of `p.addEventListener`.

Comment: I also tried your "window" solution, and it works.  Thanks